# jQuery Validate using onclick handler not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I want to use jQuery Validate to validate some form fields using a anchor onclick handler as follows but it doesn't seem to work?

```
<input type="text" id="StartDate" name="StartDate">  
<input type="text" id="EndDate" name="EndDate"> 

<a class="btn btn-primary js-add" href="#">Add</a> 




 <script>
   $(document).on('click', '.js-add', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       var validator = $("form").validate({
          rules: {
              StartDate: {
                 required: true
              },
              EndDate: {
                 required: true
              }
          },
          messages: {
              StartDate: "The Start Date is required",
              EndDate: "The End Date is required"
          }

       });

      if (!validator.valid()) {
          console.log("invalid");
          return;
      }

      //  otherwise do stuff but we dont want to submit form
   });

 </script>
```

I want to validate the fields and if they are valid do some other stuff inside the handler but I dont want to submit the form as I have another button for submitting the form. The `validator.valid()` function in the above is always true. When I submit the main button i dont need to validate the above fields as they are not mandatory - this is just for some client side interactivity that i need to validate the above fields.

is there any way I can achieve the above?

Comment: Wouldn't this work? `submitHandler: function(form) { /* do anything except  form.submit();*/ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
  if (!validator.valid()) {
      console.log("invalid");
      return;
  }
```

should be

```
  if (!$("form").valid()) {
      console.log("invalid");
      return;
  }
```

Your main problem is `var validator = $("form").validate({` function is not returning a boolean. try logging return value, you will see an object being returned not a boolean.

**`.validate()` doesn't return a boolean, it sets up validation.**

**To determine whether a `<form>` or input element is valid you call `.valid()` to get a boolean result.**

Hence your above `if (!validator.valid())` will not work & thus it never execute the `console.log("invalid");` line.

Check this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/ENjRgK)

Answer (score 0):

add these attribute to input element

```
data-val="true" data-val-required="your error message"
```

then run this code on click of your anchor

```
$(this).validate();
```

your must also refrence [jquery.validate.js](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)